# "conda install pip" changes python version . How to avoid this?

Tags: pip, conda, python-3.7, python-3.8

I am encountring the following issue. When creating a brand new environment in conda and installing `pip`, the default version of `python3` is switched from `3.7` to `3.8`. Why is this and how can I avoid this? The exact steps are below.

Thank you

```
conda create -n myenv
conda activate myenv
# python3 --> python3.7.4
conda install pip
# python3 --> python3.8.2
# pip -V --> pip 20.0.2 from /mypath/conda/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never installed `python` explicitly into your new env, so what you see after `conda activate myenv` is still the same python from your base env. Now when you do `conda install pip`, `conda` recognizes that `python` is a requirement of `pip` and therefore downloads and installs python (also check the output of the `conda install pip` call, where it will list `python` under the `The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED`). Since it has no further info, it just grabs the latest one. So your python version is never actually changed, there just never was a python in your venv when you created it.

To fix, explicitly install python into your environment with required version when creating it:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
```